# Why does it say "Sorry, we can't accept this question"?

Tags: support, questions

I've tried asking a question but the page shows the message:

> Sorry, we can't accept this question.

Here are the exact characters typed into the textbox:

- Question Title:

  > what's a consumer-tech weblog / website?
- Question Body:

  > Hi all, what's a consumer-tech weblog / website (and why is it called that way) ?
- Tags:

  > vocabulary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are automated filters in place that prevent questions from being asked which are likely to be closed. In your case, your question was very likely to be closed as *general reference* or *off-topic*, and the SE framework discovered this and prevented you from asking the question.

There is more information here: [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/323179)

Answer (score 4):

There are certain quality filters we apply to incoming questions.

Make sure your question has

- a clear title
- a reasonable *explanation* of what your question is, sharing your research on the matter
- correct use of English and actual sentences

Also, if your question is so brief that it could be looked up in a dictionary or reference book/site trivially, it might not be a good fit here.